# gazebo model dynamically modified by programming

Tags: ros, gazebo, stl, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
How to modify the model in gazebo like stl file by C or C++?
Example:
I load a face model on gazebo,
and I want to revise small portion of face model (lips) when speaking.
How to do that? Is there any tutorials?
I have found the gazebo Model Creation Tutorial
http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/doc/Gazebo-manual-svn-html/tutorial_model.html
But it's in XML format,so how I can change it by programming?
I can't find any information about that.
Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9425/gazebo-model-dynamically-modified-by-programming/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi sam,

A while back, I was trying something similar (walking legs), but I had to abandon it. Perhaps what I found could be of help, but I should warn you, my approach is rather hacky.

Gazebo runs as a server and you can connect to it using the client/server interfaces in libgazebo. The documentation with an example is available in the [Gazebo manual](http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/doc/Gazebo-manual-0.5-html/libgazebo_usage.html).

Also, the ROS wrapper for gazebo very nicely uses these interfaces to expose some topics and services in ROS. You can find the code on your machine at this path:

```
$(find gazebo)/src/gazeboros.cpp
```

Specifically, you might want to look at functions used to retrieve and manipulate models at run-time:

```
gazebo::Model* model = dynamic_castgazebo::World::Instance()->GetEntityByName(your_model_name));
const std::vector children = model->GetChildren();
// iterate using variable 'iter'
gazebo::Body* body = dynamic_cast(*iter);
const std::map* geoms = body->GetGeoms();
// magic happens here
```

Sorry I didn't get any further, but I'm interested in what you find.

Best,
Nikhil

PS: The model and entity names should be carefully specified to match the XML file that is loaded.

---

Originally posted by [scribbleink](https://answers.ros.org/users/647/scribbleink/) with karma: 116 on 2011-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2